# Error: "URL required authentication"

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to move to Magento 2 finally. 
And was trying to install a [module](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-magento2) from GitHub via composer.

I tried it on my localhost first and everything worked perfectly, 
I executed: `php ./vendor/composer/composer/bin/composer require adyen/module-payment`, then I was asked to log in `repo.magento.com` which I did, and it installed with no problems.

But, when I try to do it on the server, I'm not asked to log in `repo.magento.com`, I just get an error that I have to:

[image]

So how do I authenticate?

Comment: You run it on the server in a way that you see error messages in windows? That's not how it works usually, can you explain what exactly you are doing?

Comment: hah... I am using WinSCP where I can enter "Static custom commands". It gives me the error in a window if I don't have the console open (there's a dialog box to enter the commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using WinSCP where I can enter "Static custom commands". It gives me the error in a window if I don't have the console open (there's a dialog box to enter the commands) –

OK that explains it. These commands then run without interactive console, but composer needs it if you did not enter your credentials for the Magento repository yet (which you did locally but not yet on the server). Use a real interactive console instead. I don't know if this is possible with WinSCP, if not, use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org) for Windows.

Comment: Oh, I see... Maybe a stupid question: Do you exclusively use PuTTy or do you also use an FTP client?

Comment: I personally use (S)FTP clients very rarely, but that's a matter of taste. If you prefer graphic directory browsing, WinSCP is still good for that purpose.